# Have function passed through constructor access class's attributes

Tags: javascript, class

How would I create a class in Javascript where I can pass in varying functions as parameters that can interact with its associated class's attributes?

```
class myClass {
 constructor (x, y, myFunction) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   myFunction();
 }
}

const y = new myClass(10, 5, () => {
  console.log(this.x);
});

const z = new myClass(11, 5, () => {
  console.log(100 + this.y);
});
```

Expected Output:

```
10
105
```

Actual Output:

```
'this.x' is undefined at...
'this.y' is undefined at...
```

I don't want to pass in parameters into the function because those parameters are going to vary. I just want to have the function access the class's attributes.

Comment: 2 issues here, 1. arrow functions don't have a this, 2. you need to bind or call a function.  eg.  change `myFunction` to `myFunction.call(this)`, and then your arrow functions to `function () {}` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Arrow function doesn't have this. So you can access like `this.x` or `this.y`

> [Arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not have its own bindings to `this` or `super`, and should not be used as methods.

- function that you are calling inside `constructor` should be called like `myFunction.call(this);` or `myFunction.apply(this);`

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(x, y, myFunction) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    myFunction.call(this);
  }
}

const y = new myClass(10, 5, function() {
  console.log(this.x);
});

const z = new myClass(11, 5, function() {
  console.log(100 + this.y);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'this"

Comment: It is a working example you can `Run code snippet`. You may have done some typo

Comment: create a codesanbox or jsfiddle and share the link here so that I can understand the error properly.

Comment: Well I just made a simple program for the example. Should I give you my actual code to check out. I don't think it's any different.

Comment: If this simple program works then actual code should also work...

Comment: Here's my code: https://pastebin.pl/view/265e0d07     Its still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232373/discussion-between-ethans33-and-decpk).

Comment: This is not full code and I can't even debug it.